# Undeleted partition

Tags: file-recovery, undelete

I had 4 partition in my laptop. C(NTFS) with 118 GB for win7 , D(NTFS) with 211 GB , E(NTFS) with 236 GB and 26 GB for ext4 partition.
Unfortunately I accidentally deleted all partition in my laptop and then created 1 partition with 230 GB. And after this I realized that I was wrong.

I use PARAGON software to recover my partitions. Unfortunately it can only find  E(NTFS) with 236 GB.
now what should I do to recover D drive?

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. First I delete new created partition and